# Bitwise Operation in C - AnyOddBit

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am having trouble with the last problem of my bit twiddling homework exercise.  The function is supposed to return 1 if any odd bit is set to 1.
Here is what I have so far:

```
int anyOddBit(int x) {
    return (x & 0xaaaaaaaa) != 0;
}
```

That works perfectly, but I am not allowed to use a constant that large (only allowed 0 through 255, 0xFF).  I am also not allowed to use !=

Specifically, this is what I am limited to using:

```
  Each "Expr" is an expression using ONLY the following:
  1. Integer constants 0 through 255 (0xFF), inclusive. You are
      not allowed to use big constants such as 0xffffffff.
  2. Function arguments and local variables (no global variables).
  3. Unary integer operations ! ~
  4. Binary integer operations & ^ | + << >>
```

I can't figure out how to do this within in those restrictions and I'd really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: So how to make the value(s) compared smaller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
!!((   ( x        & 0xff)
     | ((x >>  8) & 0xff)
     | ((x >> 16) & 0xff)
     | ((x >> 24) & 0xff)
) & 0xaa)
```

The "inner" bit, which ORs together each source octet, will give you an octet where each bit is set if the equivalent bit is set in any of the source octets. So, if one of the odd bits is set in the source octets, it will also be set in the target one.

Then, by simply ANDing that with `0xaa`, you get a zero value if no odd bits are set, or a non-zero value if any of the odd bits are set.

Then, since you need 0 or 1, and you can't use `!=`, you can acheive a similar effect with `!!`, two logical not operators. It works because `!(any-non-zero-value)` gives `0` and `!0` gives `1`.

---

In order to do it with 12 operators only (rather than 13 as per my original solution above), you can remove the `& 0xff` for the `>> 24` value since it's not actually necessary (zero-bits are shifted in from the left):

```
!!((   ( x        & 0xff)
     | ((x >>  8) & 0xff)
     | ((x >> 16) & 0xff)
     | ((x >> 24)       )
) & 0xaa)
```

In fact, you can do even better than that. The final `& 0xaa` will clear out all the upper 24 bits anyway so no `& 0xff` sections are needed (it also fits on one line as well):

```
!!((x | (x >> 8) | (x >> 16) | (x >> 24)) & 0xaa)
```

That gets it down to nine operators.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now!  Thanks!  I only need to figure out how to decrease the number of operators by 1 now.  Apparently I am only allowed 12 operators for the function and this has 13.

Comment: @Cory, no fair changing the rules after the game has started :-) However, you can get rid of `&0xff` for the `>>24` value - it's not actually needed.

Answer (score 4):

You could do your ORs ahead of ANDs:

```
((x>>0) | (x>>8) | (x>>16) | (x>>24)) & 0xaa
```

The initial shift `(x >> 0)` will be optimized out - it's there for consistent look.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use the || operator, only logical or.

Comment: @Cory, that _is_ the logical or. The one you're allowed to use is the _bitwise_ or `|`.

Comment: I misspoke, sorry about that.  I am allowed to use the bit-wise or, not logical or.

Comment: @CoryHarrell You can always play an innocent trick to replace logical ORs with bitwise for a small change in semantics that does not matter in this case.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, your latest edit is back to the original problem, how to do it without `!=` :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help all.  This homework is done and I am getting a better understanding of how all this works.

Answer (score 1):

`0xaaaaaaaa` is basically `(0xaa << 24) | (0xaa << 16) | (0xaa << 8) | (0xaa)`, and that is allowed, isn't it?